# Basic guide line for asp.net mvc beginner

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Still i am not familiar with asp.net mvc. Now asp.net mvc is very popular. Before learning it I like to know few things like:

1. If there is no concept of viewstate then, how control state is maintain during postback? If discuss it in details and if possible give me sample code for persisting control state in mvc.
2. In webform we often use update panel and other controls of ajax control toolkit. So tell me how people embed ajax functionality in mvc? One option is jquery, but is there any other option too? Is there anything like update panel or ajax enabled controls?
3. You said it is possible to work with asp.net webform and mvc in same project. So tell me, how data can be pass to webform or aspx file?
4. How very easily we can migrate any asp.net webform project to mvc?
5. Is there any easy small project based on mvc, which beginner can dowload and go through the code, to understand flow of mvc project? Just like any shopping cart.
6. What is strongly type & partial view in mvc?

I have no idea about mvc project type. That is why many question is coming to my mind. Please do not feel irritate to answer all this. I apologize for all the above basic question.

Comment: Thomas, you've asked too many questions at once here. Please break them out into individual posts (before you post them, do please check that there isn't already an answer on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Here's a good place to start: http://asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is borderline subjective and might be closed but I will give it a go at my responses to your questions.

1. The web, by nature, is stateless.  ViewState and Postback are .NET concepts that are not natural to the HTTP protocol.  If you absolutely must keep persistence, you will need to look at cookies/session.
2. You can use a framework (jquery and jquery UI, YUI, etc) or roll your own javascript functions.  The concept of web controls (though they 'could' be used in MVC) is gone.  You will use standard input, select, button HTML controls.
3. I have not done this, I cannot provide much help here
4. Depends on the project and how it was written/coded.  There is no straightforward 'conversion' that one can do.  MVC vs WebForms are two different paradigms.
5. [MVC Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) and [MVC NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/)
6. Strongly typed views are views that are passed a class (model) that has a specific set of properties defined.  Using this model, you can pass only the data you need for that view, do type checking when posting back a form, etc.  A partial view is simply a view that does not contain all of the layout (master page) stuff.  It is to be used to simply display a subsection of a web page (think of a panel)